# Can somebody tell me how can provide spacing between the three sections in this html/css code?

Tags: html

I have created this web page. I want to provide spacing between the sections. I have used margin attribute but then the three sections don't stay in one line and the third one jumps to new line. I have used 12-column grid layout.
    This is the link to my html/css code  https://jsfiddle.net/wgeaa25v/

```css
h1{
 font-family: sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
}

*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
 width: 95%;
 margin: auto;
}


/**Large devices**/
@media(min-width: 992px) {
 .col-lg-1, .col-lg2,  .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, 
 .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12 {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
    /*margin: 5px;*/
  
 }
 .col-lg-1{
   width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-lg-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .col-lg-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-lg-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-lg-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-lg-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
 }

 /**Medium devices**/
 @media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
  .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, 
  .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12 {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .col-md-1 {
    width: 8.33%;
  }
  .col-md-2 {
    width: 16.66%;
  }
  .col-md-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }
  .col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
  .col-md-5 {
    width: 41.66%;
  }
  .col-md-6 {
    width: 50%;
    background: gray;
  }
  .col-md-7 {
    width: 58.33%;
  }
  .col-md-8 {
    width: 66.66%;
  }
  .col-md-9 {
    width: 74.99%;
  }
  .col-md-10 {
    width: 83.33%;
  }
  .col-md-11 {
    width: 91.66%;
  }
  .col-md-12 {
    width: 100%;
 } 
}

p{
 width: 90%;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 color: black;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 clear: both;
}

#chicken, #beef, #sushi{
position: relative;
left: 1%;
top: -5px;
float: right;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 30%;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1.2em;
margin: 0;
}
#chicken{
 background: pink;
}
#beef{
 background: green;
}
#sushi{
 background: violet;
}

section>div{
 border: 3px solid black;
 padding: 5px;
 /*margin: auto;*/
  /*margin: 1px;*/
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Module 2 Assignment</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mod2.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Our Menu</h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
   <!--<div>-->
   <section>
   <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div id="chicken"><h3>Chicken</h3></div>
    <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus dignissimos aut quasi quibusdam aspernatur possimus officia nulla consectetur velit! At, asperiores dolorem. Et iure assumenda, repudiandae laudantium, voluptatibus ex dignissimos, eum quaerat ducimus cupiditate corporis totam. Illo, alias voluptatem accusamus ut natus consequuntur quis laboriosam doloribus porro vero assumenda quo temporibus quos quam quisquam, libero quod, itaque eius sit ducimus totam iste possimus architecto debitis?
    </p>
   </div>
   </section>
   <section>
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
  <div id="beef"><h3>Beef</h3></div>
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus dignissimos aut quasi quibusdam aspernatur possimus officia nulla consectetur velit! At, asperiores dolorem. Et iure assumenda, repudiandae laudantium, voluptatibus ex dignissimos, eum quaerat ducimus cupiditate corporis totam. Illo, alias voluptatem accusamus ut natus consequuntur quis laboriosam doloribus porro vero assumenda quo temporibus quos quam quisquam, libero quod, itaque eius sit ducimus totam iste possimus architecto debitis?
   </p>
  </div>
  </section>
  <section>
  <div  class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
  <div id="sushi"><h3>Sushi</h3></div>
   <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus dignissimos aut quasi quibusdam aspernatur possimus officia nulla consectetur velit! At, asperiores dolorem. Et iure assumenda, repudiandae laudantium, voluptatibus ex dignissimos, eum quaerat ducimus cupiditate corporis totam. Illo, alias voluptatem accusamus ut natus consequuntur quis laboriosam doloribus porro vero assumenda quo temporibus quos quam quisquam, libero quod, itaque eius sit ducimus totam iste possimus architecto debitis?
   </p>
  </div>
  </section>
 </div>
 
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using more than 1px of margin? You can also use `margin-bottom: 10px;` if you only want a margin on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

you could have created one section and then do the column thing inside. Like

```
 <section>
   <row class=”container">

      <div class="col-md-4">
         Your content 
       <div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         Your content 
       <div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         Your content 
       <div>

   </row>

 </section>
```

This way they stay in one line and it's cleaner.

But if you wish to use 3 sections, you can do a "section{box-sizing: border-box}" in your Css. This allows th section use up holder div but be on one line, thats if you didn't specify width. Hope this helps